# Can my boss ask people if I'm truly sick?

Tags: canada, rights

I work in a store that's attached to another store that my boyfriend works at. He recently got sick for a week then I got sick shortly after. When he returned to work my manager went to talk to his boss and asked if I was lying about my sickness. Can my manager ask this question?

Comment: Plus you provide paperwork, right? Doctor sertificate.

Comment: Don’t know Canadian specifics. But in the Netherlands, your manager going to (indirectly) tell your boyfriend that you are sick, sounds like a privacy violation issue.

Comment: A more interesting question might be if the person he asked was allowed to *answer* questions about the health of another person.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they can ask. Employers can even hire a private detective to figure out if you were truly ill. And in the U.K., if you’re a police officer, you can actually be investigated by the police (because they are your employer, they couldn’t investigate anyone else for this reason).